# new-line character encrypt and decrypt to display on website

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, newline

I encrypt post data from text area with new-line character like this:
"A(newline)
 B(newline)
 C"
with openssl_encrypted and insert the result to mySql. When decrypt and show on the website, the result becomes:

"A/r/nB/r/nC"

How to encrypt and decrypt string with new-line characters and display exactly what it was?

Comment: Thanks but I tried 
$decrypted_content = nl2br(openssl_decrypt($content, 'aes-256-cbc', $keyword));
The result is the same.

Comment: Oh I misquoted the question then.

Comment: /r/n or \r\n?
In first case, I don't understand why it's outputted like this. In second case, nl2br would work.

Comment: Are you outputting to a textarea again or do you want the HTML representation? If you're outputting to a textarea you don't need to change anything (I assume the forward slashes are a typo).

Comment: Problem solved!
I use mysql_real_escape_string($string); before encryption so the input has been changed. Encrypt $string only that works.

Answer (score 0):

use php function nl2br(string);
ex:-

```
<?php 
echo(nl2br("A/r/nB/r/nC"));
?>
```